# Payment responce works on test mode but not live mode

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Magento 1.9 with a realex payments plugin, at first we had our response page set to oursite.com/realex/response and this worked fine without ssl installed both in test mode and live mode, as soon as we installed the ssl from lets encrypt it fails, the payments go through but the response fails! Yesterday we changed the response url to  oursite.com/index.php/realex/response and it worked with the ssl on for the first time, but it still fails when live, we get the 3d secure process screen, the payment goes through but the response always fails. I hope somebody can help its driving me mad getting passed between the host, realex and the plugin developers.